# Redrawing the interface after rotating the device in iPad app using Xamarin and MvvmCross

Tags: ios, rotation, xamarin, device, mvvmcross

I'm using Xamarin with MvvmCross to create an iPad application. In this application I want to support rotation in such sense that the layout is adjusted automatically when the rotation event occurs.

I'm aware of the GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations and the ShouldAutorotate methods, which I have tried to override to catch the event and reset observable properties in the ViewModels I use. Also, the Views have been set up in two tries:

1) Setting up the control (i.e. a label) to be bound to the screen properties:

```cs
var theLabel = new UILabel(new RectangleF(0, 0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, 30));
```

2) Setting up the control (i.e. a label) to be bound to the screen properties through observable ViewModel properties which are set in the GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations and ShouldAutorotate methods of the View. However, the value is not bound here, but just set:

```cs
var theLabel = new UILabel(new RectangleF(0, 0, ViewModel.TheLabelWidth, 30));
```

I have tried to set the width accordingly through a bindingset in a delaybind, but the width property is not able to be set in the .For(lambda expression) as I would expect.

Whatever the cause is, it seems that the interface is not redrawn. The value in the ViewModel does get set. Anyone any suggestions on this one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to handle UI related tasks in the ViewModel? The main reason you should use MVVM pattern is to separate the logic from the UI. Logic goes to the ViewModel and the UI goes to the View. So you shouldn't put any UI measurement and rotation handling to the ViewModel since it's not part of the logic and can't be reused on other platforms.

BTW if you want to handle rotations automatically you should use constraints or use a tool that allows you to create automatic layouts (i.e. http://www.toptensoftware.com/xibfree/).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read more about the MVVM pattern.

**There should not be any UI related values \ properties in the view-model!**

This means, no screen coordinates to position controls, no color values, no font names, absolutely nothing related to the UI!

The view-model should always be view and platform agnostic.

You should handle all the view related things in the platform specific view code (on iOS, UIViewController for example)

If you need to have specific UI related values (control position, visibility, etc) depending on the values from the view-model, then  you should use a **value-converter** (read about them here https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Value-Converters)

Second, I don't understand exactly what you are trying to achieve with the code you posted, but make you sure you are using the iOS layout system correctly.Use the **AutoLayout** to position and size the controls which will make your UI look and work on any screen size, any iPhone and any iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Yout viewmodel needs to send a message to your view with a messenger (like MvxMessenger)